# как определить последнюю измененную таблицу в postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть база с многочисленными таблицами. Задача определить какая таблица последний раз была изменена

Comment: `UPDATE t1,t2 SET t1.f1=t2.f2, t2.f2=t1.f1 WHERE t1.id=t2.id;` - какая таблица последний раз была изменена, t1 или t2?

Answer (score 2):

Решение громоздкое и прямолинейное, но работоспособное.
Можно использовать триггеры для каждой из контролируемых таблиц. Триггеры будут отслеживать необходимые для контроля изменения и писать результат в отдельную таблицу-журнал изменений.

```
-- журнал изменений
CREATE TABLE audit(
   op                text      NOT NULL,
   tmstamp           timestamp NOT NULL,
   table_name        text      NOT NULL
);

-- функция аудита изменений таблиц
CREATE FUNCTION public.process_audit()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO audit SELECT TG_OP, now(), TG_TABLE_NAME;
   return NEW;     
END;
$BODY$;

-- создадим несколько таблиц для целей тестирования
CREATE TABLE public.t1
(
    fld1 integer NOT NULL,
    fld2 text,
    CONSTRAINT t1_pkey PRIMARY KEY (fld1)
);
CREATE TABLE public.t2
(
    fld1 integer NOT NULL,
    fld2 date,
    fld3 text,
    CONSTRAINT t2_pkey PRIMARY KEY (fld1)
);
CREATE TABLE public.t3
(
    fld1 integer NOT NULL,
    fld2 numeric,
    fld3 timestamp,
    CONSTRAINT t3_pkey PRIMARY KEY (fld1)
);

-- для каждой таблицы нужен простой триггер такого вида 
-- (на примере триггера для первой таблицы t1)
CREATE TRIGGER t1_trg
    AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE 
    ON public.t1
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.process_audit();

-- для удобства создания триггеров для всех таблиц, которые 
-- необходимо контролировать, можно использовать функцию, создающую 
-- необходимые триггеры у таблиц, имена которых заданы маской, 
-- передаваемой в качестве параметра этой функции. 
-- Стиль маски - как у опции LIKE SQL-операторов
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.trigger_creator(mask text)
    RETURNS SETOF text 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $function$
declare
    rec record;
begin 
    for rec in select * from pg_tables where tablename like mask loop
        execute 'CREATE TRIGGER ' || rec.tablename || '_trg ' ||
            ' AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON ' || rec.tablename ||
            ' FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE process_audit();';
        return next rec.tablename; 
    end loop;
end
$function$;
```